# Snowflake snowpipe files are not auto ingesting after adding file into AWS s3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created snowpipe for one of snowflake table. Source file will be landed in AWS S3 bucket at periodical time, So followed below steps to create snowpipe:

- Created external stage
- Queried the files using "PUT" command (Able to see the list of available files in result panel)
- Created snowpipe
- Configured SQS notification on top of S3 bucket
- Added one sample file and its noy loaded automatically
- Altered snowpipe using following command:
  alter pipe snowpipe_content refresh;
- The file got added into snowflake target table after some time.

Can someone please help me to figure out what I missed on snowpipe setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below setps to trouble shoot your snowpipe:

1. Check the status of your snowpipe is `RUNNING`

```sql
SELECT SYSTEM$PIPE_STATUS('pipe_name');
```

2. Check copy history for the table associated with snowpipe. Ensure the file is not loaded from the list / errored.

```sql
SELECT
        *
FROM
    table(
       information_schema.copy_history(
           table_name=>'table_name', 
           start_time=> dateadd(hours, -1, current_timestamp())
       )
    );
```

3. Validate your snowpipe load

```sql
SELECT
        * 
FROM
    table(
      validate_pipe_load(
        pipe_name=>'pipe_name',
        start_time=>dateadd(hour, -1, current_timestamp())
        )
    );
```

If above steps looks good, Might be issue with your SQS notification set up:

Follow the snowflake article by referring below link:
[Snowflake KB](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Autoingest-not-working-for-Snowpipe)

Comment: Thanks! Yes issue with sqs notification setup!